# ELisp: forward references (reference a symbol before it is defined)

Tags: emacs, reference, elisp

How do you go about solving this problem?

Suppose I want to write a function that does the following: if the user has library X installed, then use function X-function, otherwise - skip?

What I tried:

```
(when (symbol-function 'X-function)
  (X-function))
```

I'm getting a warning for this code - so what is the right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
(when (fboundp 'X-function)
    (X-function))
```

The docs at http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Cells.html says about symbol-function

> If the symbol's function cell is void, a void-function error is signaled.

I'm guessing that is what you are seeing.  On the other hand, fboundp just returns t or nil depending on whether the function exists.

Answer (score 4):

The way to suppress this compiler warning is with something like:

```
(declare-function X-function "ext:X-library.el")

(when (fboundp 'X-function)
     (X-function))
```

Here X-library is the name of the library that X-function is defined in when the library is there. The byte-compiler will then do the following:

1. It will look for the library in the load path.
2. If it finds it, it will check that the function has been defined.
3. If it does not find the library it will assume that it will be when the library is there and pass on without error.

Thus if there is no X-library it won't complain, but if there is one and it does not define the function then it will. This means that if an updated version of the library does not contain X-function then you will know when you try to re-compile your code.

If you look up the documentation for declare-function you will find that it can also check the argument list of functions.

Incidentally If you get similar warnings about undeclared variables you can suppress these with:

```
(defvar X-variable)
```

However it is important not to set the variable even if you know what value the library sets it to as this could change in a later version.

This gives you one version of the program that works whether or not X-library is present. You might prefer to have two versions, one for when X-library is present and one for when it is not. This can be done with a macro:

```
(defmacro run? (function &rest args)
  "Expand to function call if function exists."
  (when (fboundp `,function)
    `(,function ,@args)))
```

Now instead of a call like:

```
(X-function a1 a2 a3)
```

You write:

```
(run? X-function a1 a2 a3)
```

If you compile it with X-library present this expands to the call to X-function. If the library is not present then it expands to nothing at all. You will not need the declare-function in any case. This gives two different versions, but it should be more efficient because the decisions as to whether the library is there or not are taken at compile time not run time.

One small caveat. If you go for this second solution you must either compile the whole program in the X-library environment or outside it. If you try loading the library half way through the program then when interpreted it will work as you might expect with the macro expanding differently before and after the load. But in a compiled program a macro is only expanded once. The test test for the library is in code that does the expanding not in the expansion, so the macro will not work the same before and after the load.

Comment: You should really backquote the entire macro body so that it always does the expected thing.

Comment: No, that's wrong, you only backquote those parts that are not to be executed when the macro is expanded. The point of the backquote is to stop that part of the macro expanding. It's certainly true that a lot of macros have the whole of the body backquoted but there is no general rule to this effect. If you really want to understand macros, there is a very good book "Let over Lambda" by Doug Hoyte. It is actually about Common Lisp not Elisp but much of it is applicable in Elisp especially as you can now have lexical binding abd closures.

Comment: My comment was prompted by your caveat about the environment in which you compiled the code, as including the test in the macro expansion would eliminate that constraint, which I felt was highly desirable.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you meant by "the point of the backquote is to stop that part of the macro expanding"? The backquoted (usually) return value, once evaluated, *is* the expansion of the macro.

Comment: Maybe I didn't express myself very clearly. You are right in to say that if you backquote the entire macro it will expand the same in all circumstances, but it will not expand to the code I want. If I did that there would be no point in having a macro in the first place as it would expand to code that did the fboundp test at runtime. If you want two versions of the entire code you need to do the test at compile time. This is what my macro does. This is, incidentally, qutie standard practice. A macro consists of code that generates more code, which then runs at run time.

Comment: The quotes parts of the macro are simply inserted verbatim into the run time code. The backquote is simply syntactic sugar for allowing you to have unquoted parts within a quoted region of the macro. It is theoretically unneccessary and older verions of Lisp did not have it. The unquoted parts are code that runs at compile time. What you quote and what you don't quote depends on when you want the code to run. The only restriction on macro is that it returns valid lisp code.

Comment: There is now a problem, which most versions of Lisp have that macros are expanded once if the code is complied but each time they are encountered if the code is interpreted. This means that macros that depend on the environment (i.e. what symbols are or are not bound) are sensitive to this environment and if the environment is changed between macro calls will behave differently if the code is interpreted or compiled. In some cases, such as this the point of having a macro is to make it behave diffently in different environments.

Comment: Incidentally, this is pointed out in the Elisp manual but the way they put it is a bit obscure. To sum up: A macro is just Lisp code that returns more Lisp code. A backquote is merely syntactic sugar that saves you from having to concatenate bits of code. There is no rule that state you have to backquote the body of a macro; in fact you can alway re-write it with no backquotes. All macros are sensitive to the compile time environement (otherwise why run them at compile time?) If compiled the macro is expanded once, if interpreted this happens at every call to the macro.

Comment: Normally this makes no difference because normally defining new varibles using, say defvar, or defining new functions have no effect on the macro. However in this case the point of the macro is that it expands differntly if X-function is defined to if it is not. This means that it will work differently in compiled code or interpreted code if you call it both before and after loading X-library. There is no way round this. This issue is something you have to be aware of if, for instance, you require a library to use an undocumented macro. Often this is the reason it is undocumented.

Comment: I still can't see why it would be desirable not to perform the `fboundp` test at run-time, but I accept that you've done it that way on purpose!

Answer (score 0):

Another case when you can get the warning that a function cannot be found is when you define a function programmatically and use **fset** to set it. The following example illustrates this and what to do about it:

```
(eval-and-compile
  (fset 'my-function1 (lambda () nil)))

(my-function1)

(fset 'my-function2 (lambda () nil))

(my-function2)

(my-function3)

(eval-and-compile
  (fset 'my-function3 (lambda () nil)))
```

If you compile this you get the warnings:

```
Warning: the function `my-function2' is not known to be defined.
```

and:

```
Warning: the function `my-function3' might not be defined at runtime.
```

The second warning goes away if you re-compile the code a second time in the same Emacs session, but the first doesn't.

What is happening here is this: When the compiler sees **eval-and-compile**, it first evaluates the body of the in the current Emacs session and then compiles it. Having evaluated the code, Emacs knows about the programmatically defined function.

1. In the case of **function1**, the byte compiler sees the function call after Emacs has evaluated the form and so you don't get any warnings.
2. In the case of **function2** the byte compiler never knows the functions is defined so you always get a warning.
3. In the case of **function3**, the first time round, the bite compiler doesn't know the function exists when it sees the function call.  By the end of the compilation it knows the function exists but it isn't intelligent enough to work out how it knows so you get a different warning.  However, if you re-compile it in the same Emacs session, it does know so the warning goes away.

Note that **eval-and-compile**, like **eval-with-compile**, look like a **progn** to the Emacs interpreter.